# How can I dynamically set the value of a cell in a column of a new row in a DataGridView in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to set the value of a cell in a new row to `Guid.NewGuid()`. I have a DataGridView in C# that is databound so I cannot dynamically add the a new row. I have tried to use `e.Row.Cells["Name of column"].value`. Unfortunately, the this only works once and then I get all zeros for any new row.

How can I dynamically set the value of a cell in a column of a new row in a DataGridView in C# Winforms?

**EDIT 1**

```
private void tartanIndexDataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded(object sender, 
                                                         DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn1"].Value = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Seems it is the add new record event from the bindingnavigator that is causing the app to display all zeros.

Comment: Can you add the code where you set the value?

Comment: Is your BindingNavigator using a BindingSource?

Comment: Yes, the same one the grid is using.